# A symbol name was expected! (near PASSWORD)

Tags: mysql

This is my first time using MySql and creating tables so I'm sorry if this is like a stupidly easy issue.

Here is the query:

```
CREATE TABLE users(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  username VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  PASSWORD VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Comment: i don't think so this is having any error, please check your setting or run this by sql console.

Comment: Good query. I checked.

Comment: Thank you! :) And any ideas as to why it would be giving false errors? O.o I am following a tutorial on creating a simple forum and I plan to build upon it. However if I am stuck with random false errors like this I could see it causing difficulties later in the process.

Comment: This is the srange behavior. I tried it with sqlfiddle. At first I got the same error. At next tries not anymore. I used MySql 5.6 . When I used MySQL 5.5. I got a different error message.

Comment: I am using 5.7 currently but okay, perhaps it was just some weird anomaly? Anyways thank you all for the help. ^~^

Comment: This code worked for me.